# Run PowerShell or Shell script from CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a (power)shell script that generates a version file used in other source files in the project.

How can I "register" this script to be used with CMake in build time? Here is what I have tried:

```
function(version)
    set(SRC version.h)
    set(VERSION_CMD ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fw_lib/version/version.ps1)
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(version DEPENDS ${SRC})
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT ${SRC} COMMAND ${VERSION_CMD}
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )
endfunction(version)
```

Note that `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` are input arguments to the script.

I get the following error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(....) failed.
make (e=193): Error 193
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it is too late, but for future:

```
# find Powershell executable
find_program(POWERSHELL_PATH NAMES powershell)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET "program"
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${POWERSHELL_PATH} "Some Powershell command")
```

Comment: Classic Windows powershell is pretty much dead nowadays. New cross-platform Powershell Core uses `pwsh.exe` instead of `powershell.exe`. So you may use `find_program(POWERSHELL_PATH NAMES pwsh)`